# Can't reference this in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a fileupload in my angular2 app, which sends the file as bytearray to a webservice. I use a file reader to create a bytearray, which has an onload-event. In this event I can't reference my uploadService using `this.uploadService`.

```
public uploadHandler(event) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
        var arrayBuffer = this.result, array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer), binaryString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, array);
        //this.uploadService.DoUpload(binaryString);
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.files[0]);
}
```

I tried to use the fat arrow, but I can't reference result anymore.

```
reader.onload = () => {
    //this.result does not exist anymore!
    var arrayBuffer = result, array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer), binaryString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, array);
    this.uploadService.DoUpload(binaryString);
}
```

Comment: `onload` passes an event object as an argument, so you may check in the documentation whether you can get your "result", which seems to be `event.target.result`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload . Alternatively, if you don't want to do that, you can still avoid using the fat arrows for **that specific case**, keeping the function declaration will effectively keep the "this" of the function declaration, hence you won't get any further problem.

Comment: You need to save the lexical scope. As a member declare private myMethod: (anyParam: any) => any; Then inside the constructor you have to implement the method that you can't refer to.

Comment: Besides, `event.target.result` theorically should be the same as `reader.result`: in your case, `var arrayBuffer = this.result` is the same as writing: `var arrayBuffer = reader.result`, since `.result` is a readonly property of the FileReader object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/result . So you have three ways to solve the issue, this last one is likely the fastest one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the fat arrow is the right way to go. and you can also get the result from the reader variable instead of this. so it could look like this

```
public uploadHandler(event) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
        var arrayBuffer = reader.result;
        var array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
        var binaryString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, array);
        this.uploadService.DoUpload(binaryString);
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.files[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try it:

```typescript
reader.onload = (event: any) => {
  console.log(event.target.result); // result should exist
};
```

Comment: Result is not a member of target: Property 'result' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Comment: @Karl: cast it as "any" instead of "EventTarget".

Comment: @Karl Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I think this should fix your problem, or at least some approach that looks similar, because you have a problem with `this` binding.

```
public uploadHandler(event) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var that = this;
    reader.onload = function() {
        var arrayBuffer = this.result, array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer), binaryString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, array);
        that.uploadService.DoUpload(binaryString);
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.files[0]);
}
```